# jQuery each is only affecting the last instance

Tags: jquery

I have got a weird jQuery issue that will most likely end up being something ridiculously minor, but after searching for a while I still can't get past it.

**The issue**
I have got a table with a list of domains. The table consists of two columns - domain name and IP address.

The IP address columns loads with the content of a loading icon, which is then **supposed** to be replace with the contents of an ajax call made.

The script is supposed to do a jQuery `each()` on a data attribute which is on the each IP column, take the data and perform a .get request which then returns that domains ip.

**The problem**
When the .each runs, it checks the ip address and only replaces the final rowsloading icon.

**Code**

```
$("[data-domain]").each(function(){
        domain = $(this).data('domain');
        tr = $(this);

        $.get( "/database/ajax/domain/check", { domain: domain } )
          .done(function( data ) {
            tr.html(data);
          });
    });
```

Comment: you continue to change the tr and the call is async, so by the time any of the callbacks are done it's already changed to the last one

Comment: The issue is to do with the scope of 'tr'.  You can add a new scoped variable or you can re-find the row when the request has completed.  Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the timing of what you're doing. You loop through some elements, and each time change a reference to the same `tr` variable to be the current element. You then make an async ajax call and register a callback. The loop continues to run and finish so naturally the value of `tr` is the last value.

*Then* your callbacks start firing, and they use the closed over value of **the same variable** (`tr`).

To achieve what you want, the obvious solution would be to create a *new* `tr` each time through the loop, which gets closed over inside your callback. To do this, simply declare it inside the loop (otherwise you're creating a global).

```
var tr = $(this)
```

Comment: Thank you. The lack of the `var` keyword on my `tr` variable was the cause of the problem.

Comment: @LeonHunter In general, if you're going to omit the var (or const or let) be sure you understand what it's doing and have a good reason. I almost never declare a variable like that.